# Java: convert StreamResult to DOM

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, xml-parsing

I am performing a xslt transformation from one xml format to another with saxon and xslt, after what transforming the result xml into Java DOM to work with it further:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("xslt.xsl")));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(inputXML)),
                                  new StreamResult(new File (outputXML)));

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(outputXML);
```

What I don't like in this situation, is creating intermediate `outputXML` file. Is it possible to avoid its creating?

Comment: Use [`DOMResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMResult.html). Read the documentation. Do a little *research*, please.

Comment: Don't know. Have been seeking the solution all day. Maybe I am too stupid for programming :(

Comment: Andreas, that probably should get moved to an answer

Answer (score 2):

The answer was provided by @Andreas. If someone is interested, the result code snippet in my case looked like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

DOMResult xmlResult = new DOMResult();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("xslt.xsl")));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(outputXML)),
                              xmlResult);

Document document = (Document) xmlResult.getNode();
```

Answer (score 0):

DocumentResult result = new DocumentResult();

transformer.transform( new StreamSource(new File(inputXML)), result );

Document transformedDoc = result.getDocument();