# Writing Out a DOM as an XML File

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, saxon

Straight [from](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) the manual:

> Writing Out a DOM as an XML File
>
> After you have constructed a DOM (either by parsing an XML file or
>   building it programmatically) you frequently want to save it as XML.
>   This section shows you how to do that using the Xalan transform
>   package.
>
> Using that package, you will create a transformer object to wire a
>   DOMSource to a StreamResult. You will then invoke the transformer's
>   transform() method to write out the DOM as XML data.

my output:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldSaxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldSaxon$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
Jan 04, 2019 3:28:24 PM helloWorldSaxon.HandlerForXML createDocumentFromURL
INFO: http://books.toscrape.com/
Jan 04, 2019 3:28:26 PM helloWorldSaxon.HandlerForXML createDocumentFromURL
INFO: javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult@3cda1055
Jan 04, 2019 3:28:26 PM helloWorldSaxon.HandlerForXML createDocumentFromURL
INFO: html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldSaxon$
```

Firstly, I'd like more meaningful output for what the `domResult` is, looks like, or contains.  More important, I believe, is iterating or traversing `document` below:

```
    public void createDocumentFromURL() throws SAXException, IOException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException {
        LOG.info(url.toString());

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
        Source source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, new InputSource(url.toString()));

        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, domResult);  //how do I find the result of this operation?

        LOG.info(domResult.toString());  //traverse or iterate how?

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
//        Document document = documentBuilder.parse();   ///bzzzt, wrong

        Document document = (Document) domResult.getNode();

        LOG.info(document.getDocumentElement().getTagName());
        }
```

That the output is "html" inclines me to believe that this is the `html`.  The desired output is that `html`, but from a `Document`, rather than a `String`.

Oracle documention on writing out a `DOM` is to parse the document.  Is this document not already parsed?  *Or, to put another way, how do I establish that it is or is not an `XML` file at all?*

So.....transform it **again**?

see also:

[Java: convert StreamResult to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587753/262852)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really just have to transform the DOM to your file.

*Example*

```java
// Create DOM
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Element root = document.createElement("Root");
document.appendChild(root);
Element foo = document.createElement("Foo");
foo.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bar"));
root.appendChild(foo);
```

You can save that DOM to a file like this:

```java
// Write DOM to file as XML
File xmlFile = new File("/path/to/file.xml");
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(xmlFile));
```

You can also just print the DOM like this:

```java
// Print DOM as XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Root><Foo>Bar</Foo></Root>
```

If you want the XML formatted:

```java
// Print DOM as formatted XML
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
</Root>
```